# Different css3 transaction speed for child and parent element

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is it possible to have different transaction speed for parent and child divs?

i.g. parent will transition in 4 seconds, while child will react on the same event in 1 second. Same properties are changed for both child and parent.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bvk4320v/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="d1">
    Parent div<br/>
    Parent div
    <div class="d2">
        HOVER ME
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.d1 {
    background-color: #F32423;
    transition: all 4s linear;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.d1:hover {
    opacity: 0.2; 
    margin-left:40px;   
}
.d2 {
    background-color: #FFFF2F;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    height: 100px;
}
```

If you hover the child div, you can see that the `transition-duration: 1s;` is ignored for the child element. What I want is to have child elements transitions 4 times faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. What is needed is to repeat the properties of the parent that should be transitioned in child element also. So in particular case, the parent on hover properties, should be also repeated for the child element.

```
.d1:hover .d2 {
    opacity: 0.2; 
    margin-left:40px;   
}
```

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bvk4320v/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can

```
.myDiv .popup {
transition-duration: 1s
}
```